# Is there a way to remotely control gas valve?

Tags: gas, natural-gas, home-automation, smart-switch

We have a short term rental home, and we have a grill that's connected to natural gas. As a prevention of hazard, is there a way to open and close the gas valve remotely? We want to be able to close it if ever a guest mistakenly leaves it on or a cleaner forgets to turn it off for some reason.

Comment: How would you know that you're not turning it off in the middle of the guest cooking something?

Comment: Albeit this is an off-topic shopping question you should Google "Wifi gas valve" and might find https://www.amazon.com/Control-Controler-Compatible-Assistant-Automatic/dp/B07X95X53D. The main issue is that you cannot operate it in the event of a power failure.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are electronically controlled gas valves.

A better idea might be to install a "grill timer". It's like a kitchen timer that you twist to set the time, but instead of ringing a bell it stops the gas from flowing.

Comment: I have used a grill with such a timer in a condo common area. I think this is the solution - more foolproof than a remote shutoff system.

Comment: Good suggestion. I looked for "grill timer" and got meat temperature type timers. The search term "gas timer shut off" was better.